# How to specify that a combination of properties implies another

Tags: rdf, owl

In OWL2, is there a way to specify that if some combinations of properties applies between to entities, than an additional property implicitly applies as well? I.e., state that if R(S,O) holds and P(S,O) holds, then Q(S,O) holds as well.

I know this is possible with Classes, but I can't find a way to do it with properties.

For instance, as a somewhat contrived example, consider properties `:is-older-than`, `:is-brother-of`, and `:is-older-brother-of`. Obviously if the first two hold between two entities, than the third will also hold, but I want tell a reasoner to do apply that property automatically, without me having to specify it.

This is similar to the `owl:propertyChainAxiom` in that it specifies an implicit property. In this case, the rules for the implicit property are different.

Alternatively, if a property can be implied based on the type of either the subject of the object, I think I can also get what I want. For instance, if I have a property `:performs-with` and a sub-property `:rocks-out-with`, and I have a class `:Band` and a sub-class `:RockBand`, I'd like to say that if the object of a `:performs-with` property is a `:RockBand`, then the `:rocks-out-with` property should also apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called property intersection.  If

> R(s,o) ∧ S(s,o) → P(s,o)

then you're saying that

> R ⊓ S ⊑ P

You're absolutely right that the counterpart is supported for classes.  It's not supported in OWL2 for properties though.  Some description logics have intersection (and other) role constructors, but not the one that OWL2 is based on.  There's some work on where they can be supported, though.  E.g., see [Cheap Boolean Role Constructors for Description Logics](http://korrekt.org/page/DL_Role_Constructors). 
[Appendix 1: Description Logic Terminology](http://www.ksl.stanford.edu/people/dlm/papers/dlhb-appendix.pdf) from *The Description Logic Handbook* also provides a list of role constructors that might be supported by a description logic (p.499):

[image: role constructors]

OWL2 supports some of these. The top and bottom properties are the universal role (and its complement).  It also supports inverses.  You get *some* of composition through property chains.